# Cannot use correctly string offset as an array

Tags: php, hook

I am using an old [PHP hook class](https://github.com/atmoner/PHPHooks) and have a problem with my PHP update
Here is the mistake I have

```
[php7:error] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot use string offset as an array in /var/www/html/libs/Hooks.class.php:202\nStack
```

Here is my source code (ligne 202)

```
function add_hook($tag, $function, $priority = 10) {
    if (! isset ( $this->hooks [$tag] )) {
        die ( "There is no such place ($tag) for hooks." );
    } else {
        $this->hooks [$tag] [$priority] [] = $function; // <-- this is problem (line 202)
    }
}
```

If I change the line that causes problem like this:

```
$this->hooks [$tag] [$priority] = $function; // <-- this is problem (line 202)
```

I only get the first letter of the content (as in the pictures)

[image]

I do not know how to solve the problem

Comment: It can be two problem: 1. $this->hooks [$tag] is string, but not array. 2. $priority = 10 change to $priority = "10"

Comment: @VasylZhuryk, $this->hooks is declared to string at top of code [see here](https://github.com/atmoner/PHPHooks/blob/master/phphooks.class.php#L32)

Comment: @Julien: FYI: https://3v4l.org/k2n0V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you defined var as a string - you cant add array elements. Your solution - to cnange library function to:

```
function set_hook($tag) {
    $this->hooks [$tag] = [];
}
```

and for better quality of the code - change function declaration to:

```
function add_hook($tag, $function, $priority = "10") {
```

Comment: Ooooh!! I did not see the solution like that !! It's perfect =) Thank you very much

Comment: @Julien You are wellcome)))